# ORDER COLUMNS TABLE VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I would like to reorder all the columns from several tables (Set as Table in Excel) one below the other adressed in the same Worksheet.

This is an example so you can have a better understanding of what I currently have:

Table1

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
```

Table2

```
Col1  Col4  Col5  Col3  Col2
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
```

Table3 (In this table, I have an extra column which I do not need)

```
Col3  Col1  Col2  Col5  Col4  Col6
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
```

Desired Result

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
```

My first solution was creating a Macro in Excel but I'm stacked with the code as I'm not an expert. The idea is to create an Array and order the columns for each table.

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim arrColOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer

arrColOrder = Array("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5")

For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)
  For Each WS In Worksheets
    For Each tbl In WS.ListObjects
```

That is the beggining of the code but I don't really know how to define the Array for each Table.

Comment: It would be possible what have you tried?

Comment: I have just added what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You're in the right direction. If you somehow fail to get a solution, I'll post a sample when I have time.

Comment: That would be very helpful because I'm stacked on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Sub CopyConcatenate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = .Columns(x)' change x to the number column you want

        '~~> Cut the range
        rng.Cut

        '~~> Insert the range
        rng.Offset(5).Insert
    End With
End Sub
```

To delete a column you would use something like this

```
Set Rng = ws.Columns(x)
Rng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: I think this not quite close to what the OP wants.